# Descriptions of Win32_Thread ThreadWaitReason values

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, operating-system, kernel

The **Win32_Thread** class is described in MSDN here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394494(v=VS.85).aspx

Problem is, the definitions for the **ThreadWaitReason** attribute are concise, to say the least.  Has anyone got any (more) verbose definitions?

Please, no purile MS bashing - even Mark Russinovich "Inside Windows..." series doesn't enumerate them!

Here's hoping

Simon

Comment: Ask a specific question, which one is unclear to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkhtkxxy.aspx) help?

Comment: Thanks, almost, but not quite 100%.  For example, what does "The thread is waiting for event pair high." actually mean?

Comment: Event pairs seem to be part of the kernel's support for LPC (Local Procedure Call). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Procedure_Call

Comment: Also, "Event pairs are used for high-performance interprocess synchronization by the LPC facility." http://netcode.cz/img/83/nativeapi.html

Comment: Please add the actual answer

Answer (score 0):

Note that Windows has never done anything with these values, they're strictly informational for debugging purposes. So, probably why you don't find much info about them.

-scott